# Apple Watch Activity App API

Tags: apple-watch, healthkit

Is there an API for the "Activity" app?  For example, I want to retrieve information from the "Exercise" section of the app (calories you burn) and I want to retrieve the personal information you type in when you first open the app.  Is that possible?  And how do I retrieve this information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no API specifically for the Activity app. You can, however, access much of the information it displays by making use of the HealthKit framework. Check out the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/healthkit/).